# How to add MD5 or SHA hash to spring security?

Tags: spring-mvc, encryption, hash, spring-security, md5

I'm working on an application using Java EE, the Spring security framework and an Oracle 11g database. I need to add an MD5 hash into Spring security and I haven't succeeded with this.

What I have done so far:

1-In the first weeks I tried to add the md5 hash to my application without adding any code to springsecuritycontext.xml and I succeeded.

This is what I have done:

In the package called ma.dyaralmansour.zkgui.policy there are two classes.The first one is called PolicyManager and this class implements the spring-security UserDetailService. The second is called LoginLoggingPolicyService and this class is called from Spring AOP as an aspect and is for logging.

So this is what I have done:

```
       *** I added an MD5Password class to the ma.dyaralmansour.zkgui.policy and I added some code to the PolicyManager class to activate the hash and it's working.
```

My problem now is:

All my passwords are hashed with an MD5 hash but I can't access the application anymore when I use the normal password.

Now I have 2 options, but I have no idea whatsoever how to implement them:

1- in the MD5password class there is a method named testPassword(String clearTextTestPassword,String encodedActualPassword)

It compares the normal password with the hashed one stored in the data base but I couldn't understand how to add it into my policymanager class.

2 - to completely remove all what I had done and only focus on the configuration of Spring security in order to hash the password and access to the application when I use a normal password.

Or is there an other solution?

http://www.mediafire.com/download/gxgda63wyhkpehn/DamPromoZK4.rar

```
<!-- Spring namespace-based configuration -->

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:zksp="http://www.zkoss.org/2008/zkspring"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop   
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">



<!-- Enable the @Secured annotation to secure service layer methods -->
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

<http auto-config="true">

    <!-- ###  If we have our own LoginPage. So we must    ### -->
    <!-- ###     tell Spring the name and the place.      ### -->
    <!-- ###     In our case we take the same page        ### -->
    <!-- ###     for a error message by a failure.        ### -->
    <!-- ### Further the page after a successfully login. ### -->
    <form-login login-page="/index.zul" 

        authentication-failure-url="/index.zul?login_error=1"
        default-target-url="/AccueilIntranet.zul" />

    <!-- ###   Tell Spring where it goes after logout.    ### -->
    <!-- ###          logout-url is a action url.         ### -->
    <logout logout-url="/j_spring_logout" logout-success-url="/index.zul" />

    <!-- ### Define the pages that are to be intercepted  ### -->
    <!-- ### It is parsed from top to bottom. Means that  ### -->
    <!-- ### the most specific pattern is standing on TOP ### -->
    <!-- ###         and the CATCH ALL is on BOTTOM!      ### -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/WEB-INF/pages/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" filters="none"/>

    <!-- ### The root page is accessible by everyone but  ### -->
    <!-- ###    internally spring makes a login and       ### -->
    <!-- ###     this user becames a UserDetails          ### -->
    <!-- ###   (in there are the ip-address and others)   ### -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" filters="none"/>

    <!-- ###           Per user one session !!            ### -->
    <concurrent-session-control max-sessions="1" />
</http>

<!-- ###   We define the kind of authentification with a  ### -->
<!-- ###          so called authentication-provider       ### -->
<!-- ###   So we have our users stored in a DB we use     ### -->
<!-- ###   our own user-service class and point to her.   ### -->
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
</authentication-provider>




<!-- ###   The Implementation of the Interface            ### -->
<!-- ###      UserDetailService for the logged in         ### -->
<!-- ###              user and his rights                 ### -->
<beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="ma.dyaralmansour.zkgui.policy.PolicyManager">
    <beans:property name="userService" ref="userService" />
</beans:bean>



<authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
<password-encoder hash="md5"/>
</authentication-provider>




    <!-- ###   This aspect call automatically the methode     ### -->
    <!-- ###   'loginLogging' which is for writing a log for  ### -->
    <!-- ###   all successfully and failed logins, if a       ### -->
    <!-- ###   methode is called that handles the             ### -->
    <!-- ###    Authentication.                               ### -->
    <beans:bean id="LoginLoggingPolicyService"
        class="ma.dyaralmansour.zkgui.policy.LoginLoggingPolicyService">
        <beans:property name="loginLoggingService" ref="loginLoggingService" />
    </beans:bean>






    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect id="LoginLoggingAspect" ref="LoginLoggingPolicyService">
            <aop:pointcut id="authPointcut"
                expression="execution(public org.springframework.security.Authentication org.springframework.security.providers.AuthenticationProvider.authenticate(org.springframework.security.Authentication))" />
            <aop:around pointcut-ref="authPointcut" method="loginLogging" />
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you reinventing the wheel? Spring Security supports password hashing out-of-the-box and it is simply a matter of configuration. Your custom implementation for the `UserDetailService` must simply return the user found for the username (not check passwords or what so ever). Spring Security will then check the password with the configured hash.

Simply configure Spring Security appropriately by adding a password-encoder to your `<authentication-provider .. >` element

```
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
    <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
</authentication-provider>
```

You also might want to check the [Spring Security documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-password-encoder)

Another suggestion for improvement is instead of using AOP for logging (assuming that is the only thing you do) implement an `ApplicationListener` and listen for [AbstractAuthenticationEvent](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/event/AbstractAuthenticationEvent.html)s. You might want to check the default [LoggerListener](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/event/LoggerListener.java) for a simple working sample.

Comment: I added this code to my springsecuritycontext.xml and i removed the MD5password class and the code i have done in policymanager class , but when i run the application and i use a normal password its does not become hashed i dont know what those lines of codes acually do can u plz explain to me more ?

Comment: how can i tell spring to read from my database and to use the hash password in order to connect to the application ?

Comment: That is done by adding the configuration as mentioned above. What do you mean by 'use a normal password its does not become hashed'? Which password, when should it be hashed? Please update your question with the current setup (configuration and code) you have now.

Comment: i added  the configuration u mentioned above and i removed anything that i have done before i only keeped the code u give it to me so when i try to login to the application using for exemple login=admin i look in my data base and the login does not become hashed

Comment: No you haven't... You haven't added the `<password-encoder />` element as in my code sample. So basically you are hashing nothing. Also as mentioend before you should not check the password in your service, spring will do that for you. Work **with** the framework not against or around the framework.

Comment: i have just update the springsecuritycontext.xml this is what i added exactly what u did mentioned , i deleted the Md5password classe and all the code that i have added in the plocymanager classe and i left only what u told me .

Comment: Yuor configuration is wrong as it contains 2 `<authentication-provider />` elements. Can you tell us which Spring and Spring Security versions you are trying to use. Finally is it possible that you zip your project so that we can take a better look.

Comment: i have just posted a link to download the project , i appreciate your help thx a lot

Comment: In your code (at least the stuff you posted) you still did not add the `<password-encoder hash="md5" />` in between the `<authentication-provider>` tags. Without that Spring security doesn't know that it should use md5 for comparing the passwords.

Comment: i dont think i have the jar file that contain class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.MD5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder , this is why it does not work right ?

Comment: Judging from the content of the zip-file you attached there are a lot more files missing. I strongly suggest you start to use something like [maven](http://maven.apache.org) or [gradle](http://www.gradle.org) for dependency and build management.

Comment: can u plz tell me what are the jar files that i need to make it work ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the new BCryptPasswordEncoder:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html

It will salt your passwords for you automatically.

I recommend BCrypt as it is strong, and slow, and has no known weaknesses. "Slowness" is actually a feature you want in a hashing algorithm, because that means it takes a longer time to crack if someone steals your passwords.

SHA 256 is weakened. MD5 is definitely broken.

Comment: can u plz explain to me more  this is the first time  i work with spring and i still dont have a clear idea about it ,  would u tell me were should   i implement BCryptpassword in  the code i  posted with my question ?

Comment: You have to be very careful with “slow”. If you're working with _session-less_ code, making everything very slow hurts a lot. The best workaround I've thought of so far is to keep the strong hashing for stored passwords, but to put a cheaper transparent in-memory cache in front so that going in with exactly the right password as was used previously can be much quicker. The idea is to make legit users on systems not under constant attack not have to pay too much of the cost.